# Walk through `rms::val.prob`

Tags: r, regression, probability, regression-strategies, calibration

The `val.prob` function in the `rms` `R` package has similarities to the `calibrate` function discussed in [another question of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561922/walk-through-rmscalibrate-for-logistic-regression), but a key difference in that `val.prob` has no notion of a probability model. Indeed, I can run `val.prob` on random data.

```
library(rms)
set.seed(2022)
N <- 100
p <- rbeta(N, 1, 1)
y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)
rms::val.prob(rbeta(N, 1, 1), y)
```

Unsurprisingly, the results show the random numbers between $0$ and $1$ to be unrelated to the binary `y`.

[image]

I have some idea of how `val.prob` works.

1. Draw a bootstrap sample of the `p-y` pairs.
2. Fit a model to the `p-y` pairs.
3. Repeat, repeat, repeat...
4. Use some kind of average to say what the true probability of $Y=1$ is for each given probability `p`.

In `R` code:

```
set.seed(2022)
N <- 500
B <- 1000
pr <- sort(rbeta(N, 1, 1))
y <- rbinom(N, 1, pr)
m <- matrix(NA, B, N)
for (i in 1:B){
  idx <- sample(seq(1, N, 1), N, replace = T)
  pb <- pr[idx]
  yb <- y[idx]
  
  Lb <- glm(yb ~ pb, family = binomial)
  m[i, ] <- 1/(1 + exp(-predict(Lb, data.frame(pb = pr))  ))
  
  if (i %% 50 == 0 | i < 6 | B - i < 6){
    print(i/B*100)
  }
}

pL <- apply(m, 2, mean)

plot(pr, pL, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1), xlab = "Asserted Probability", ylab = "True Probability")
abline(0, 1)
```

[image]

However, I simulated my data! I know that `pr` generated `y`, so the calibration should be pretty good, not curved like it is. Even with a large sample size of $50000$, that curve remains when I do my own implementation. When I use `rms::val.prob`, even for a sample size of $500$, I have no such issue.

[image]

What step(s) am I missing in my implementation?

Comment: [This Cross Validated answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/349489/247274) might have some of the secret recipe, but it also looks to be more related to `rms::calibrate` than `rms::val.prob`. Ditto for [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/383759/247274).

Comment: Taking a peek at the source code, the glm is fit suing the logit of the probability (essentially the linear predictor of the model, not the response on the probability scale).  Try that and see if it gives you the expected outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I dug into the source code.  There is no bootstrapping in `rms::val.prob`, that would likely occur in `calibrate` or `validate`.  The two lines you see (logistic calibrated and non-parametric) are obtained in the following way:

For logistic calibration, we fit a logistic regression using the logit of the probability as the predictor.  Here is some code to do just that

```
set.seed(0)
p = runif(1000)
logit_p = qlogis(p)
y = rbinom(1000, 1, p)

mod = lrm(y~logit_p)
pp = seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)
pred = plogis(predict(mod, newdata = list(logit_p = qlogis(pp))))
```

For the non-parametric curve, Frank uses a lowess smoother.

```
sm = lowess(p, y, iter=0)
```

If we plot the two curves against the output of `rms::val.prob`, we see the two lines lay on top of one another.

```
val.prob(p, y)
lines(sm, col='red')
lines(pp, pred, col='blue')
```

[image]

The source code is available by running the following code.  Just replace `<file name here>` with a file path.

```
sink(<file name here>)
rms::val.prob
sink()
```

Comment: +1 and green checkmark: I've even written my own basic implementation in Python!. I have to wonder, however, why there's no bootstrapping in this function. It doesn't seem much different, philosophically, from `rms::calibrate`.

Comment: @Dave assessing the calibration and estimating the optimism on the calibration slope and itntercept are separate tasks.  The latter requires bootstrapping.  The former does not